# Lower bound error

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

I am following [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) tutorial on `Lower_bound()` in C++. I have made a simple code to find a number in a vector lesser than or equal to a number from the vector + any number that I want. My code goes like this

```
cout << *lower_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), A[x] + 3);
```

where the vector `A[]` is sorted. But the code points it to a number greater than the sum of both the numbers.

For example if my vector has values as `0, 3, 5, 8, 12` and I want it to print the nearest number lesser than or equal to `A[3] + 3 = 11` it should give output as `8` but it gives the output of `12`. Any reasons?

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> A = {0, 5, 3, 12, 8};

    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    cout << "A[3] = " << A[3] << endl;
    cout << *lower_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), A[3] + 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are understanding lower_bound() wrongly. It returns an iterator to the first value which does not compare less than A[3]+3. Where 8<11 is true, 12<11 is false.

Comment: Then is there a standard function in C++ to find the nearest number lesser than or equal to any given number, though I know about upper_bound() - 1 method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the largest number not greater than your target, you can use `std::greater<>` and reverse iterators (or sort by `std::greater<>`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {0, 5, 3, 12, 8};

    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    std::cout << "A[3] = " << A[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << *std::lower_bound(A.rbegin(), A.rend(), A[3] + 3, std::greater<int>{}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,last) which does not compare less than val.

In your case it is not returning the last value less than 11. It returns the first value **not** less than 11, which in your example is 12.

Comment: Thanks. Then is there a standard function to find out the value less than or equal to a given number?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but you might try searching/asking as a new question.

Comment: The logic behind is to use `std::lower_bound` to get, from the range [first, last), a range [first, last*) where a condition (in general a "less than" predicate) is true for all of [first, last*).